# Basic integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrator

I want to understand, how to calculate voltage in output of integrator, if there is some offset voltage in "+" input. So there are my formulas:

[image]

Is it right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftJgX5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Look up Bonnie Baker (and Jim Todsen) once from Burr Brown on these topics. For example, here's one from [Bonnie Baker](http://nic.vajn.icu/PDF/Burr-Brown/apnotes/AB-048.pdf). There will be lots of good white papers from these two on the topic.

Comment: Seems ok. But, sorry, I don't know CircuitLab. Start @t=0 with -0.5V. Slope 5kV/s or 5v/ms.

Comment: You need to mark your schematic to show the assumed direction of your named currents.